# Update Loop of Death, workaround requires bitlocker recovery key to boot into safe mode

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-update, bitlocker, wsus

One day our users turned on their laptops just to realise their screen was stuck at boot because it was waiting for an update to complete. This spinning wheel takes forever saying "Working on updates 0% Don't turn off your PC, this will take a while". This only happens on windows 10 1803 clients. The only  workaround we have at the moment is to use the legacy advanced boot option  since we cant boot directly into safe mode using a windows 10 usb image, fa bitlocker recovery key is required for this operation due to disk encryption in the mix. Upon successful startup in safe mode a message is triggered which says "The updates could not be setup. Changes are reversed" after the computer should start again without issues. Analysing the log files shows the problematic patch was the cumulative update 06/2019 for Win10 1803 which couldn't install properly. This problem is then somehow curtailed via this workaround.

Though the above workaround seems to solve the problem it is a very cumbersome process for tech support since they have to go around each pc to perform these tasks thus can be time consuming and unproductive.

Is there a way the above solution can be centralised by way of maybe suspending Bitlocker > deinstalling or skipping that kb and then starting the pc into normal mode successfully once that particular update is detected?

Are there any other known centralised workarounds/solutions in case someone has already encountered this problem.

Some tips will be appreciated.

Comment: It's almost like it could be worth it to have IT test patches before deploying to the entire business...

Comment: Bitlocking the system partition is fine only as long as there's no problem.